# Generating unique base-64 ID's in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, cryptography, unique

I'm making an application in which I need to generate Unique IDs.

When generating IDs the best way to avoid clashes, is it simply brute force generate-then-check'ing, or is there a way to garuantee unique generation.

I'm sure the brute force method would do well for a while however I have a feeling companies like Google aren't using this method.

The other things is how to actually generate them in node.js.

I thought of generating int's from '0 - 63' and then parsing to base-64 like this:

```
var map = {
    0:0, 1:1 ... 16:"Q" ... 63:"/"
}; /* I used object so you can see the indexes, 
this would be an array - or even a string? */
for (var i = IDLENGTH, id=""; i--;) id+=map[~~(Math.random*64)];
```

However this seems inneficient, especially having the `map` in the first place.

I saw this peice of code in another SO post

```
console.log(new Buffer("Hello World").toString('base64'));
> SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=
```

Which seems to make more sense, but this doesn't seem to fit what I need, isn't this conversion of char-sets?

Comment: Generate a UUID, then convert it to base64.

Comment: Use a counter and base64-encode that?

Answer (score -1):

This is quite an open question, but you probably want to generate an [`UUID`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). Basically it's a random 128 bit number. If done correctly, the probability for a duplicate is [extremely low](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates). I believe for most applications it's not strictly needed to check, but you might still want to do it.

Use a well tested library instead of implementing this yourself, I recommend [`node-uuid`](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid). Generating good random numbers is very similar to crypto operations - it's not trivial to get right.

Comment: Would appreciate if there was an explanation for the downvote. I can go into further detail why OPs approach doesn't make sense or help with the confusion around encodings.